# Неправильное присваивание значения

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $text =$_POST['y_text'];
    $step =$_POST['step'];
    $mas =array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
    echo <<<_END
    <pre>
    <form action="cesar.php" method="post">
    <input class="text" type="text" name="y_text" size="15" value="$text"/>
    <br />
    <input class="step" type="text" name="step" size="3" value="$step"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="y_submit" />
    </form>
    </pre>
    _END;

    $mod_step = $step / 26;
    $mod_step = (int) $mod_step;
    if($mod_step > 1) {
        $step=$step-$mod_step*26;
    }

    $max_size= strlen($text);
    for ($s = 0; $s < $max_size ; $s++)
    {
      for ($j = 1; $j <= 26; $j++)
      {
      if ($text[$s] == $mas[$j]) 
      {
       echo $text[$s];
       echo $mas[$s];
       echo $j;
       echo "<br />";
       $catch=$j;
       $catch=$catch+$step;
       if ($catch > 26)
         {
         $catch = $catch - 26;
         $text[$s]=$mas[$catch];     
        }  
       else
        {
         $text[$s]=$mas[$catch];  
        }
       } 
      }  
    }
    echo '<br />';
    echo $text;
    ?>
```

Пока не рабочий вариант преобразования кода шифром Цезаря.

Почему-то переменной шаги $j равны $catch, в чем проблема, ведь кроме экскримента ничего не увеличивает j.

Comment: Т.е., переменные имеют одинаковое значение и вам это не нравится? :)

Comment: да, и это очень не нравится

Comment: хм... а какое значение должно быть у $j, по вашему, после того как вы присваиваете точно такое же значение в $catch? Что должно случиться с $j ?

Comment: Добавил весь текст программы, можете протестировать.

Comment: "ведь кроме экскримента ничего не увеличивает i." - что???? ЭКСКРИМЕНТА???


И вообще у Вас там нет переменной $i.

Comment: поправил, это была логичная ошибка

Comment: @HappyCougar, он имеет ввиду, Ваш *экскримент*. Вы наверное имели ввиду инкремент?

Comment: ошибки такие ошибки)))

Comment: @HappyCougar, ты [звезда][1] =)


  [1]: http://vk.com/typical_proger?z=photo-30666517_296158725%2Falbum-30666517_166427528%2Frev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$catch=$j;
$catch=$catch+$step;
```

А чему равно $step? Вы уверены что оно в данном случае не равно 0?

```
$step =$_POST['step']; //Чему $step равно здесь?
$mod_step = $step / 26;
$mod_step = (int) $mod_step; // Если $step было "ерунда", то $mod_step = 0
if($mod_step > 1) { //следовательно это не выполнится
    $step=$step-$mod_step*26;
}
$catch=$catch+$step; //и это будет равнозначно $catch = $catch + 0
```

Отсюда и получается - $j == $catch

Т.е. сделайте вывод на каждом из упомянутых участков и смотрите где сбой. Мне кажется - в $_POST